# How to connect to SharePoint in Postman using user id and password instead of client id and client secret?

Tags: rest, http, sharepoint, oauth-2.0

I want to connect to SharePoint by using username@company.com and password instead of client id and client secret. Do I need to get any authorization for my ID? If yes, how to get? I know the process for fetching authorization for client ID and client secret.

In this URL: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/_layouts/15/user.aspx

I add my user id and password with permission levels as "Full control".

But in this URL: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx

I am able to see only client id and client secret. Not my user id.

When I send POST request using Postman it is giving me **"error": "unsupported_grant_type"**.

Postman Inputs:

```
POST https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{tenant_id}/tokens/OAuth/2


Headers
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body (x-www-form-urlencoded)
grant_type: password
username: username@company.com
password: password
resource:00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{tenant}.sharepoint.com@{tenant_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharePoint rest api does not support "Password Grant Flow". You can either use "Client Credentials Flow" or "Implicit Flow".
```

If you want to allow users to use their username & password, Use implicit flow.

**NOTE:** **User will always require to sign in to get access token. You can not simply pass username and password with post request.**

Here is the complete guide for configuring azure ad app for implicit flow : https://frankchen2016.medium.com/how-to-access-the-spo-rest-api-using-implicit-authentication-flow-40d65750554f